# How do I serve another existing website on my local Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, request

So take this example:

- User goes to site (localhost:8080)
- The Node.js webserver makes a GET request to <kbd>https://example.com</kbd>
- The Node.js webserver also scrapes the content of that site
- It then responds to the user (on localhost:8080) with the Content-Type, Status code, and content of the original site.

I have done this in such a simple method before previously.

What happened? Every time you make any type of GET request in Node.js (with `fetch`, `axios`, `http/https`) I always get the error `AggregateError` with multiple errors regarding something like "not being able to reach {github.io's IPv6 address}", ONLY if I make multiple requests at a time. If I make one of these requests, it works fine.

The reason that it's GitHub.io's IP address is because the site I want to mirror onto the server is <kbd>https://parking-master.github.io/FPS/</kbd>

This is the code that produces that error (for debug purposes or more info):

```js
app.get("*", async function(req, res) {
  let path = req.url;
  try {
    function request(response) {
      const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data);
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", response.headers["content-type"]);
      res.statusCode = response.status;
      return res.send(buffer);
    }
    try {
      let response = await axios.get(address + path, { responseType: "arraybuffer" });
      request(response);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("Error caught during request:", err);
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Error caught during scraping:", err);
  }
});
```

And this is the error:

> AggregateError
> at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1103:18)
> at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1161:5)
> at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1161:5)
> at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1161:5)
> at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1161:5)
> at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1638:3)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {code: 'ENETUNREACH',[errors]: [Error: connect ENETUNREACH 2606:50c0:8001::153:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)

If anyone knows why this problem occurs, let me know. More information is that this error usually occurs when requesting unique files from the original site (like .mp3, .glb) and not on common files (like .html, .css, .js)

My actual question is, am I doing it the right way, and if not, how do I *actually* host a webserver that mirrors another website's pages onto itself?

I had a hard time explaining this question, but I hope everyone understands it.

**Note:** I am using express.js to host the webserver. It would be great if this could be done using express.js, but I'm willing to use some other type of software.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @jabaa sure! I'll put some code in the question that I've used when the error was created.

Comment: That code snippet isn't a complete example. Please fill all the variables and provide the necessy request.

Comment: You said that the error only occurs when you do multiple requests at the same time, but the code you posted doesn't show multiple requests anywhere. Could you elaborate and also provide a minimal reproducible example like jabaa mentioned.

Comment: @Andria Sorry about that, there are multiple requests occurring when the server makes one request, then the requested html page has more requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to implement is reverse proxy. You can install `http-proxy-middleware` from npm and use it in your node app. Below is the example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

app.use('/', createProxyMiddleware({
  target: 'http://example.com', // target host
  changeOrigin: true, // needed for virtual hosted sites
}));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on http://localhost:3000');
});
```